# how I want use a new contract sending a deployed ERC20 token from one to another

Tags: erc-20

A address send eth to my contract And I will pay A another token

tha's my function code ,but do not work.Where am I wrong ?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;
contract ICOProxy  {
address tokenaddr;
function () payable public{
 uint256 amount = msg.value* 10 ; 
    address se=msg.sender;
    bytes4 methodId  =bytes4(keccak256("transferFrom(address,address,uint256)"));
    tokenaddr.call(methodId,owner,se, amount);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add the right interface, there's no need to manually try to construct the call data. Something like this should work:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract ERC20 {
    function transferFrom(address, address, uint256);
}

contract ICOProxy  {
    address tokenaddr;  // initialize this somewhere
    address owner;      // initialize this somewhere

    function () payable public{
        uint256 amount = msg.value * 10;

        // Use require(...) here to revert the transaction of the transfer fails.
        // The owner will need to call approve() to allow this call to work.
        require(ERC20(tokenaddr).transferFrom(owner, msg.sender, amount));
    }
}
```

Comment: Try your code but not use. I don't know why~

Comment: Is it not need gas ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Every transaction requires gas. If you saw an error, please tell us what it was.

Comment: "A address send ether to this contract, this contract will send to A address some specified  ERC20"  I tried the code but not work..

Comment: "not work" is not an error message. I can't help you if you won't tell me the problem.

Comment: no error ~  This is my test tx 
 https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0xf6add8bb4a03aa3c8c4e2a46935435514e3f74471f935172027f0b445d6701fd

Comment: Where's the code for the contract?

Comment: pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract ERC20 {
    function transfer(address, uint256) public;
}

contract ICOProxy  {
    address tokenaddr=0xa12622662aAFe7bd7029e81c55E8dECE2dC4fb73;  // initialize this somewhere
    

    function () payable public{
        uint256 amount = msg.value * 810;

        // Use require(...) here to revert the transaction of the transfer fails.
        // The owner will need to call approve() to allow this call to work.
        ERC20(tokenaddr).transfer(msg.sender, amount);
    }
    function set(address c) public{
        tokenaddr=c;
    }
}

Comment: https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x12cc5a981f24ad40fdca7ec3be369805ed6c8be6

Comment: And where's the code for the token? (https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0xa12622662aafe7bd7029e81c55e8dece2dc4fb73)

Comment: My guess would be that you never called `approve()`.

Comment: Thank you !!      I found where it was wrong ，My Contract have not enough ERC20 token